# Why does this Spek on action not run?

Tags: android, kotlin, spek

When I run this example code, all the code in the "on" action does not run in Android Studio. Do you know why? what is missing?

```
import org.jetbrains.spek.api.Spek  
import org.jetbrains.spek.api.dsl.describe  
import org.jetbrains.spek.api.dsl.given  
import org.jetbrains.spek.api.dsl.it 
import org.jetbrains.spek.api.dsl.on

@RunWith(JUnitPlatform::class) class SpekTest : Spek({
    val x = 2
    val y = 3

    given("x = $x and y = $y") {
        val sum = x + y

        on ("why does this not run?") {
            it("should be that x + y = 5") {
                assertEquals(5, sum)
            }

            it("should be that x - y = -1") {
                val subtract = x - y
                assertEquals(-111, subtract)
            }
        }

    } })
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to update the spec version to be

```
testCompile group: 'org.jetbrains.spek', name: 'spek-api', version: '1.1.4'
testCompile group: 'org.jetbrains.spek', name: 'spek-junit-platform-engine', version: '1.1.4'
```